# final keyword guarantee clarification regarding concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am currently going through Core Java, Vol I book, Chapter 12 - Concurrency.

There is a section in the book relating final keyword, which states:

> There is one other situation in which it is safe to access a shared field — when
> it is declared final. 
> Consider
> `final var accounts = new HashMap<String, Double>();`
> Other threads get to see the accounts variable after the constructor has
> finished.
> Without using final, there would be no guarantee that other threads would
> see the updated value of accounts—they might all see null, not the
> constructed HashMap.
> (Horstmann, 2018)

I have tried to create an example demonstrating, that non-final field may be read by the other thread before it is initialized.

```java
class SharedResource {
    private int value;

    public SharedResource(int value) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class NonFinalExample {

    private static SharedResource sharedResource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> sharedResource = new SharedResource(42));
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            if (sharedResource != null) {
                int result = sharedResource.getValue();
                System.out.println("Thread 2: Value is " + result);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Thread 2: Shared resource is not initialized yet");
            }
        });
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

The problem with it is that I can't understand, how in the example above `thread2` can see `sharedResource` as not null while having uninitialized `sharedResource.value` at the same time.
Isn't `SharedResource` object is assigned to `sharedResource` variable by `thread1` only after the initialization is complete and the object is created?

Would appreciate any help relating the subject

Comment: use Integer instead of int 
int = default value it holds automatically as soon as it is declared.

Integer = null by default

Comment: @jarvo69 Thank you for the feedback. Could you elaborate on how this answers the question asked?

Comment: The problem with demonstrating such behaviour is that there is nothing you can do to enforce this behaviour (i.e. the field `SharedResource.value` is written after `SharedResource sharedResource` is written). This might happen only on February 29 during the time when 20_000 users simulationously access your system. Without using `final` there is simply no guarantee that your code will not fail at some time - and you wont find out that "some time" is the worst time: on a weekend during the holidays, during a sales meeting, when 1000s of customers want to buy from your shop.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thank you for the answer. If `SharedResource sharedResource` is written after the `SharedResource.value`, then how can other thread see uninitialized value (`sharedResource.value`). As I understand, in this case no threads can read a value from `SharedResource sharedResource`, hence the problem with not using final is invalid

Comment: If creating the `SharedResource` is on a hot code path the JVM could (at runtime) inline the constructor into the caller and proceed as follows: create a new `SharedResource`, store the reference into the `sharedResource` field, call the super constructor (from `Object`), then initialize the `value`. For all code running on thread 1 everythink looks correct - and without `final` or synchronization that is the only guarantee that the JVM makes: that the code running on the same thread after the constructor has finished doesn't notice.

Comment: There is this other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588556/why-does-attaching-byteman-rule-to-my-method-accidentally-fix-an-exception) where someone tries to find a NullPointerException occuring sometimes in production after upgrading from Java 7 to Java 8 - and this is exactly the kind of problem you can expect if `value` is not final but `SharedResource` is shared between threads. You just don't want to be in that persons place just because your simple test was unable to show this possible problem.

Comment: @ThomasKläger One last question - could you please provide any reference material for the described behavior (when the reference is stored in `sharedResource` prior to the finish of constructor call)?

Comment: The definite reference is in the Java Language Specification [Chapter 17.4 Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) and [Chapter 17.5 `final` Field Semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5). That the reference is stored in `sharedResource` prior to the finish of the constructor call is a possible consequence of "method inlining" (i.e. the code for the constructor is inlined into the caller) followed by "statement reordering" - both common optimizations done by the JVM.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Thank you very much. I already found the JMM reference to read more about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cited text is misleading at best.

The line `final var accounts = new HashMap<String, Double>();` can’t be a field declaration as the `var` keyword is only allowed for local variables. Discussions about field initialization are pointless for local variables.

Further, the phrase “after the constructor has finished” is meaningless when the constructed object is improperly published to other threads. Concurrent access implies the absence of an order. But note that this is specifically about a scenario of improperly published objects. For correctly published objects, you don’t need `final` fields.

It’s also important that the problem of potentially seeing inconsistent values for improperly published objects is not just that a thread might see `null` for a reference field. It may also see a non-`null` reference but an inconsistent state of the `HashMap` instance. And as `HashMap` is a mutable object, note that the guaranteed consistent state is the state of the `HashMap` when finishing the constructor, as long as no subsequent modifications happen; if there are any modifications after the constructor, all bets are off. Making a field `final` can not replace proper synchronization for mutable data.

When you have a data race like in your example code

```java
if (sharedResource != null) {
    int result = sharedResource.getValue();
    System.out.println("Thread 2: Value is " + result);
} else {
    System.out.println("Thread 2: Shared resource is not initialized yet");
}
```

you may not only have the potential result of reading `0` in `getValue()`, it’s even possible that the first read of `sharedResource` in `sharedResource != null` sees a non-`null` reference but the other read in `sharedResource.getValue()` sees `null` and produces a `NullPointerException`.

As said earlier concurrent access (without correct synchronization) implies the absence of an order. Therefore, you can not reason about the expected outcome of the two reads of the field `sharedResource` by assuming that the reads happen in a particular order.

But, as said in the comments, a possible outcome does not imply that you can force this outcome in an example program. Programs running a single time are especially unlikely to produce rare conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As an addition, this article https://medium.com/codex/method-inlining-in-java-84caec9b3e18 put me on the right track to enforce constructor inlining which can lead to the problem described in my original question